# How to pass a multidimensional associative array in URL

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, get, associative-array

I have been Googling for hours but I can't make heads nor tails out of it. I have a multidimensional associative array like this:

```
$mArray = array(
   array("m" => "0"),
   array("m" => "1"),
   array("m" => "1")
   );
```

I would like to create the array with PHP GET request:

```
mywebsite.com/file.php?.......what do I put here?.....
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use array access notation like this

```
mywebsite.com/file.php?item[0][m]=0&item[1][m]=1&item[2][m]=1
```

It would be simple to use nested loops to build this string - don't forget to URL encode the values

```
$query_string = '';
foreach($mArray as $key => $array) {
    foreach($array as $k => $v) {
        $query_string .= 'item[' . urlencode($key) . '][' . urlencode($k) . ']=' . urlencode($v) . '&';
    }
}
$query_string = substr($query_string, 0, 1); // trim extra &
```

If you needed to handle arrays of arbitrary dimensions, you could obviously modify this into a function which could be called recursively to get to as many levels as possible.

Comment: Thanks, I cant seem to get it to work...Shouldn't `$mArray` be somewhere in the URL?

Comment: @Youss I just put `item` as the parameter name as you didn't specify what the name was you wanted the parameter passed as.  You can simply substitute `item` for whatever parameter name you choose.

Comment: The whole thing depends on 'getting' the URL first, how do I do that with GET?

Comment: @Youss So I thought you wanted to take the values in `$mArray` and pass to another page via `$_GET`, so you needed to build the query string.  No matter the logic is the same. If you are trying to populate `$mArray` from a GET request you just need to have the query string formatted as I have shown.

Comment: What do you mean by "'getting' the URL"?

Comment: But the query string already has `$mArray` inside of it, how can that be when it is not created yet with the URL? Im sure this is the right answer by the way thats why I accepted, but I cant make it work..

Comment: So first things first. Are you trying to populate `$mArray` INTO a query string or are you trying to populate it FROM a query string? What do you mean by "the query string already has `$mArray` inside of it"?

Comment: "'getting' the URL" I mean this is the starting point. First I have parameters in the URL. Second: the parameters are converted in to an array. Then the array is further processed

Comment: Trying to populate `$mArray` INTO a query string

Comment: The system tells me one comment every 15 sec. then it lets me hanging for two minutes:)

Comment: Then you just need to form the query string for the URL as shown in my example. Make a request to `yourdomain.com/yourscript.php?item[0][m]=0&item[1][m]=1&item[2][m]=1` in that script run var_dump`$_GET['item']` to see what you get.

Comment: If you need to create the query string from `$mArray` you can just do it like I have shown in my sample code.

Comment: Im getting this `array(3) { [0]=> array(1) { ["m"]=> string(1) "0" } [1]=> array(1) { ["m"]=> string(1) "1" } [2]=> array(1) { ["m"]=> string(1) "1" } }` Is this expected?

Comment: @Youss Yes that is your array. That is the exact array structure you posted in your original question.  The shows you how PHP will use the array access notation in the query string and build a multi-dimensional array for you.

Comment: @Yous So now you should know both the format required in the query string to pass arrays (of any number of dimensions as you just keeping add new brackets to add dimensions). And you should know how to create such a query string from an existing PHP array.  So hopefully you should have what you need.

Comment: It finally worked. I was doing something incredible stupid...I was filling in 'image' between the brackets as key while it should have been html 'img'......Thanks again:)

Comment: @MikeBrant Your code is hurting my eyes.  `http_build_query()`